# Is it safe to query my database for every page load?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, web

Meaning every page in my website queries something from the database.

The query in itself is very small and the time it takes to load is unnoticeable, but I'm wondering if it's okay to do this for every page since I don't really know much about how querying from the database works and whether doing it multiple times, and in my case for every page load, affects anything significantly.

Comment: In general it is important how many concurrent request/queries you are expecting and how much resources you have at your disposal(computational power). In case you are not expecting heavy traffic, you are okay. If you expect heavy traffic you can find querying database can be bottleneck. You can use load testing to find out how much your software can handle.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but consider what would happen if the application displays page 1 of 2, then while the user is looking at that another session changes the data, then the user requests page 2 of 2. Now perhaps if you'd cached the whole lot at the start you would avoid inconsistency - but then you wouldn't be showing the latest data so perhaps those cached results would be invalid. So it depends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are OK to query the database on every page load.

Think about websites like Facebook. When you visit the site it needs to know who you are - it gets that from a database. It needs to know all of the status updates that it's going to show you - it gets that from a database. When you hit the bottom of the news feed and it gets more for you to read - it gets that from a database.

Answer (score 5):

As with all things, the answer is *it depends.* :-)

Most web sites you visit queries something from a database on every page load. If the queries are crafted well, they look up just the data they need, and avoid scanning through a big database. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU)) to help with this.

Another strategy is to use a fast cache in RAM for data that is needed frequently. RAM is thousands of times faster than disk drives. You might like to familiarize yourself with the [Numbers Everyone Should Know](http://brenocon.com/dean_perf.html). Those numbers are just examples, but the intention is to get programmers to think about the fact that moving data around has different cost as you use RAM vs. disk vs.network vs. CPU.

P.S.: Please don't buy into the myth that you're not good at computers because you're a woman. *Everyone* starts out as a novice, no matter what their gender or background. Only through practice and study do any of us learn this stuff. I recommend seeing [Hidden Figures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wfrDhgUMGI), the story of the women who did pioneering math and programming for NASA.

Another notable woman is [Margaret Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Hamilton_(scientist)), who practically invented the profession of "software engineering."

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. Most web applications have to query the database for each page load (usually several times), since most of the page content comes from the database.

If you're concerned about performance, think about this: is the query different for each page? Or is it loading the same data over and over? If it keeps querying the same thing (like the current user's name), you can improve performance by storing the data in the application's session state. But if it's different (like how many unread messages the user has), you'll need to run the query each time.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine visiting a website which has features like 'whois online' or a messaging system, when ever you click on another page the site needs to update the database so that it can keep track of where you are on the site. If you receive a private message it would be accessible on the next page click since the database would have been updated when the message was sent. The trick is to run queries only to perform tasks which is required at that time. For instance if you were looking for a username in the database, if you searched the whole database it will run a lot slower as it needs to search the whole database. If you searched by a particular column it will be faster, it will be even faster if you used things like limits such as LIMIT in the query.